# Parsing XML when inside tags vary

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have a use case in which I want to parse an XML file of the following kind and create an HTML report out of it.

```
<?xml version = '1.0'?>
<outer tag>
<first_tag>
  <some Random xml tag>
         <another tag>
         </another tag>
  </some Random xml tag>
</first_tag>
<first_tag>
  <some Random xml tag>
         <another tag>
         </another tag>
  </some Random xml tag>
</first_tag>
<second_tag>
  <some Random xml tag>
         <another tag>
         </another tag>
  </some Random xml tag>
</second_tag>
```

The problem with this XML structure is that I only know that the entire XML will be wrapped in Outer tag  and the second level tags can only be first_tag or second_Tag.  I don't have any idea about what will be coming inside those second level tags.

My html is supposed to look like:

```
  Elements inside outer_tag
      First_tag children 
        " <some Random xml tag>
           <another tag>
           </another tag>
         </some Random xml tag>  "  // XML structure itself 
      First_tag children :

        " <some Random xml tag>
           <another tag>
           </another tag>
         </some Random xml tag>  "  // XML structure itself 
        Second_Tag children :

        " <some Random xml tag>
           <another tag>
           </another tag>
         </some Random xml tag>  "  // XML structure itself
```

I tried jaxb  and other XML parsers. Since I have no idea about inner structure I am finding it difficult to pen an algorithm. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XSL Transformation would work great in this scenario. XSLT is commonly used to transform XML into other formats like HTML. Here is a transformation that will get you what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="first_tag|second_tag">
        <xsl:copy-of select="./*"/>            
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

See it working here: http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rLS